# How to open a link in a default user browser in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I wonder how to open a link in a default user browser using Qt (that would open it across all platforms (Win Mac Lin))?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In the doc: QDesktopServices

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl

```
bool QDesktopServices::openUrl ( const QUrl & url ) [static]
```

> Opens the given url in the appropriate Web browser for the user's desktop environment, and returns true if successful; otherwise returns false.

Comment: It doesn't work to put a string directly as an argument to that function. To open a URL from a string, you need to use the `QUrl()` function like this: `openUrl (QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/"));`

Comment: Where does my answer suggest to use a string directly? You can see it says it needs a Url object to be passed.

Comment: I know. I just posted that comment to help people understand that. When I first saw it, I thought I had to use a string directly and it took some time before I understood that wasn't the case. I just wanted to help other people who would think the same thing.

Comment: For some reasons it doesn't work if the link contains an anchor, e.g. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget

Answer (score 39):

You can try this code

```
QString link = "http://www.google.com";
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link));
```

Read [QDesktopServices](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) and [QUrl](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qurl.html) to get further information.

Comment: No, this is actually the single proper SO-style answer with the working example how `openUrl` works. No need to go elsewhere and check specs.

Comment: Don't forget to add `#include <QDesktopServices>` to the top of your file

Comment: Think this is the better answer. Copy & paste – just works, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

you are looking for openUrl() in the desktop services class

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QDesktopServices.html